# FTP Access to Temp Folder

Tags: azure-web-app-service

Under Advanced Tools (Kudu) Environment, it says there is a Temp folder at D:\local\Temp.

From the console, I could create files in the Temp folder. Is there FTP access to this folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot.

I just checked: after logging in with FTP you can see the same folders you can see with Kudu under `Debug console`. The TEMP folder is *not* part of this.

> Unlike Persisted files, these files are not shared among site instances. Also, you cannot rely on them staying there. For instance, if you restart a web app, you'll find that all of these folders get reset to their original state.
>
> [...snip...]
>
> Another important note is that the Main site and the scm site do not share temp files. So if you write some files there from your site, you will not see them from Kudu Console (and vice versa). You can make them use the same temp space if you disable separation (via WEBSITE_DISABLE_SCM_SEPARATION). But note that this is a legacy flag, and its use is not recommended/supported.

Taken from [Understanding the Azure App Service file system](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Understanding-the-Azure-App-Service-file-system).

Of course you *can* access the TEMP folder programmatically.